# Running a function automatically on serverless deploy in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, triggers, aws-lambda, mariadb

I want to create mariadb and create tables on it automatically on serverless deployment, so that I do not need to create any tables manually in my aws project. I searched in internet but found only manual methods. Is there any method which I can achieve this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at my work place, we use `serverless-transmogrify` to  do that. It lets us execute `sequelize` migrations. The table structures created as `sequelize` migrations and we make use of this serverless plugin to create the tables via this plugin once the deployment is completed.

Check it out.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-transmogrify

reference: https://sequelize.org/